# Only merge the files that I have modified in a branch into another branch

Tags: git, merge, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm new with git and I'm using bitbucket with source tree.

I have two branches, and I need to merge the commits in branch01 into branch02.

How can I do that?

I have tried to merge, but it merges all changes between the two branches. I don't want that, I only need the commits done in this branch01.

I have also tried rebase, but it does a very strange thing. I have read the Atlassian [documentation](https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/08/21/merge-or-rebase/) about it but I haven't understood anything.

The problem here is the following:

Both branches come from the same branch (Develop). But I didn't create it at the same time.

There are some changes in branch02 that they aren't in branch01 and when I do the merge appears conflicts with this changes.

I only want to merge the files that I have modified and added on branch01 into branch01. Is there a way to do that?

Any idea?

Comment: Doing `git checkout branch02 && git merge branch01` should do what you need. If you are looking for something else, then give some more details about what you exactly want.

Comment: I have added more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the merge strategies..

- Checkout to branch01 i.e. `git checkout branch01`
- Use command `git merge -s ours branch02`

This will merge branch02 into branch01 keeping the branch01 versions of the conflicting files.

Hope it answers your query.